# What switches are set by VS2017 when debugging in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2017

When I launch a webapi or angular project from visual studio 2017 debugging in Google Chrome it opens a new browser and seems to be a clean slate in that no links are shown or user profiles.

How can I find out what switches are being passed to get chrome to be a "Blank Slate" like Visual Studio 2017 does?

I have set google chrome to be the default debugging browser and can see the path it launches from.
[image]

Comment: I'm also curious about this! I want to keep whatever arguments it uses by default so I can add additional ones of my own.

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the debugging option javascript  debugger for asp net (Chrome and Explorer).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but I need to keep that checked and would still like to know what that changes in Chrome.